# Mirror-like of source code tree applying beautifier to modified files only

Tags: rsync, io-redirection, bourne-shell

I keep two copies of the same source code tree: One is the "working copy", and the other is the "stored copy". When I finish editing the "working copy", I refresh the "stored copy" with `rsync` (only modified files will be copied and, moreover, deleted files in the working copy will be deleted in the stored one as well). There's also a SCM, but it takes place later, after the "stored copy", so we can ignore the SCM here.

But now I want to apply a code beautifier when doing the refresh from the "working copy" to the "stored" one. The code beautifier can be applied through stdin/stdout redirection, but, AFAIK, `rsync` doesn't allow going through a stdin/stdout filter when performing the copy.

I want to beautify only the modified files, because I don't want to modify the timestamps of unchanged files in the "stored copy". The beautification rules are different for the "working copy" and the "stored copy", so the beautifier can't be applied to the working copy.

How can I do this? Any solution that works on UNIX would be acceptable, although I prefer Bourne shell scripts, or C programs. If `rsync` could be used in some special way for doing this, it would be fine as well.

Comment: I know you wrote that we can ignore the SCM here, but one way to do this would be to use the SCM...

Comment: @StephenKitt Yes, that was the first idea, but I was told it's not a good idea to commit files into a SCM after applying a modification to them (in this case a beautification filter). Thus, the decision of the intermediate "stored copy": that's the one beautified, and also the one being built, so all SCM commits belong to tested files.

Comment: The general approach for this kind of problem isn’t to modify the files while they’re being committed; instead, it’s to fail the commit if the modified files don’t meet the “beautification” criteria. This ensures that commits are valid, but it’s up to the developer to make them so (which can involve automated tools, of course).

Comment: Which SCM do you use? Why don't you beautify the "working copy"? Instead of answering in comments you should [edit] your question to add more information. I suggest to use separate commits for the manual modification and the result of the beautifier.

Comment: @Bodo personally I don’t like separate beautification commits; if a project has a style guide, or is based on an ecosystem with a style guide (*e.g.* Go with its formatting rules), every single commit should adhere to the style guide.

Comment: @StephenKitt I agree if the beautification affects only the new or modified lines.

Comment: @StephenKitt My goal is not that commits fail if they don't meet the beautification criteria (although that would be a bonus, of course), but the solution to your other part of the sentence ("it's up to the developer to make them so, which can involve automated tools"). So, I'm after the automated tools here. I'm not beautifying the "working copy" because the code guidelines are different from the repository ones. Thus the need for the "stored copy", which follows the repository guidelines and is built and tested before committing.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by “the code guidelines are different from the repository ones”?

Comment: @StephenKitt I mean that the style guidelines in the repository are different from the style guidelines used in the "working copy". So, beautification cannot be done "in-place", but using an intermediate copy (what I called the "stored copy" here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the constraints explained in the question and comments, I would start by removing the differences between the style guidelines used for the working copy and the stored copy. However I understand that can be very difficult, so feel free to ignore that advice.

I don’t think `rsync` (*i.e.*, filtering the files while they’re being copied) is the right place to try to apply “beautification” before committing the “stored copy”. If you can use the SCM, I would piggy-back off of that; for example, using `git`, after `rsync`:

```
git diff --name-only -z | xargs -O beautifier
```

will run `beautifier` on all changed files, assuming it can work on files given as parameters.

If you can’t (or won’t) use the SCM, you could use the `rsync` logs (see the `--log-file` and `--log-file-format` options) to find out what `rsync` copied, and run the beautifier on those files only.

If `rsync` logs aren’t exploitable, there is still another way to go about this: run the beautifier on every single file in the “stored copy”, outputting to a temporary file, and compare the output to the original. If the beautification changes a file, copy the output back over the original.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think you covered all the possibilities here. As you said, I tend to prefer getting the list of files with the SCM because as you show, you can get the list of files without a temp file, while the `rsync` solution would need to use a temp file. Of course I'll need to filter out some extensions so that I only beautify C/C++ files, but with the SCM it can be done as a one liner, so thanks a lot!!